# view's frame not releasing its memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm not able to rectify the situation which is arising in

```
customTabView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-49, self.view.frame.size.width, 49);
```

where, memory assigned every time and not releasing after dismissing the view.

Well, the situation is that, I have created a simple login screen as `rootviewcontroller`, then through a button (login button) presenting a `tabviewcontroller` where, I have added a view as subview on tabviewcontroller, on that subview four buttons are there, through delegate I'm controlling the tabIndex, everything is working fine, but when I check about the leaking memory, above view.frame keeping the memory.
I'm posting the image, please look at this,

[image]

Here is my TabView Controller with custome tabbar.

[image]

Any help will be appreciable.

UPDATE:

Here is my complete code.

From Login Page:

```
- (IBAction)clickLoginBtnAction:(id)sender {


    tabControler = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];

    [self presentViewController:tabControler animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

From Tabbar Controller:

```
#import "TabBarController.h"

@interface TabBarController ()<TabBarIndexProtocol>{

//    CustomTabViewController *customTabView;
}

@property (strong) CustomTabViewController *customTabView;



@end

@implementation TabBarController

@synthesize customTabView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    customTabView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomTabViewController"];
    self.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    [self frameCustomTabViewOnTabBar];
    customTabView.tabBarIndexDelegate = self;

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

//    customTabView.view.frame = nil;
}

// For Screen Rotation

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {

        [self frameCustomTabViewOnTabBar];

    }];
}

-(void)frameCustomTabViewOnTabBar{

    customTabView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-49, self.view.frame.size.width, 49);
    [self.view addSubview:customTabView.view];
}


# pragma mark - TabBarIndexProtocol from CustomTabBarClass

-(void)tabBarIndexSelected :(int)tabNumber{

    NSLog(@"%d",(int)tabNumber);

    [self setSelectedIndex:tabNumber];
}
```

In My CustomeTab.h File:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TabBarIndexProtocol <NSObject>

@required

-(void)tabBarIndexSelected :(int)tabNumber;

@end

@interface CustomTabViewController : UIViewController

@property(weak) id <TabBarIndexProtocol> tabBarIndexDelegate;

@end
```

and from its .m file

```
#import "CustomTabViewController.h"

@interface CustomTabViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomTabViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)tabNumberOne:(id)sender {

    [self.tabBarIndexDelegate tabBarIndexSelected:0];
}

- (IBAction)tabNumberTwo:(id)sender {

    [self.tabBarIndexDelegate tabBarIndexSelected:1];
}


- (IBAction)tabNumberThree:(id)sender {

    [self.tabBarIndexDelegate tabBarIndexSelected:2];
}


- (IBAction)tabNumberFour:(id)sender {

    [self.tabBarIndexDelegate tabBarIndexSelected:3];
}
```

Thats all, where I'm mistaking :( .

Comment: Your question does not make sense. A view frame cannot hold, or leak, memory. It's a scalar value. The line of code you posted has nothing to do with the cause of leaking memory.

Comment: That code will not present the tabView controller. Please show complete code of how you present it and how you dismiss it.

Comment: You should not try to add subviews like buttons to a `UITableViewController`. A `UITableViewController` only manages a table view, and is not designed to support other subviews.

That might be the cause of your problems, but you need to post the code that's setting up your view controller, adding views to it, and presenting it in order for us to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @DuncanC Thank you for your quick response, but when i ran my project it started with 31.3MB of memory, now when I presenting the TabBarcontroller it increases to above 32 MB, thats fine but when i dismissing the TabBarController, it should release the memory, but not releasing here.